# I am trying to create a 3D matrix using a for loop

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to create this matrix but am getting an error message. I also tried initialising an empty np.array but it does not like it! can some help?

```
size = [5, 9, 9, 9, 5]

# Loop 4 times, i=0,1,2,3
for i in range(len(size)-1):
    # create weights for layer i with the given matrix shapes
  weights[i] = np.random.random((size[i+1], size[i]))
```

I am getting the following error

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-91-48898eba4562> in <module>()
>       7   print('\n')
>       8     # create weights and bias for layer i with the given matrix shapes
> ----> 9   weights[i] = np.random.random((5,3))
> 
> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Comment: Without seeing the code for `weights` we can only guess as to what the issue is. Please post a [mre] of the issue. From the error message, though, it seems that `weights` is an empty array or list. Either you have to pre-fill it, or insert items instead of adding them at a particular index.

Comment: weights does not exist. I am trying to create this matrix

Comment: Why do you expect `weights[i]` to work if it's empty? There's nothing there at any index.

Comment: I did initialise the weights list but got some errors due to the dimensions of some of the items not matching. can an array be initialised to be flexible with the possible parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to edit something that doesn't exist. First declare `weights = []` and then instead of using `weights[i] = np.random.random((5,3))`, use `weights.append(np.random.random((5,3)))`

Comment: the example provided is just a sample and am trying to create something that can generalise to many possible scenarios/ configurations

Comment: This method can do just that. Instead of appending `np.random.random((5,3))`, you can append whatever matrix/element you want.

Comment: I am trying to design the architecture for an artificial neural net and the user will provide an input with the number of layers and number of neurons in each layer and from this value I am looking to create a loop to generate random weights depending on the values inputed. so if the user inputs say [5,9,9,9] I would like to create a matrix which will have three dimensions; the first will be for which layer (I.e. 5,9,9,9) then the second dimensions will be the number of neurons in current layer and number of neurons in next layer. sorry for long reply!

Comment: I got this to kindof work

`weights = []

size = [5, 9, 9, 9, 5]

# Loop 4 times, i=0,1,2,3
for i in range(len(size)-1):
  weights.append(np.random.random((5,3)))

weights_array = np.array(weights)
weights_array.shape`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you should be able to loop as you said and append an item using `weights.append(np.random.random((size[i], size[i+1])))`